# 404 on refresh with Vue Router and Nginx

Tags: nginx, vue-router

I have a project on an Ubuntu server that produces a 404 error when refreshing or manually typing the URL. For example, I can go to example.com but I cannot go to example.com/home or refresh while on that page without getting a 404. Clicking on links work as expected. I'm using Vue router in history mode and have added the following in the http section of the nginx.conf file:

```
server {

            listen 80;
            server_name example.com;

            root /var/www/example.com;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
    }
```

I can test the configuration with sudo nginx -t and it passes, but I'm still getting 404 errors. It might be worth mentioning that I have multiple server blocks on this server.

Comment: why dont you add `index index.html` before your `location /` line

Comment: yeah, I eventually found that I needed to do that. working fine now.

Answer (score 8):

I modified the nginx.conf a bit and this worked:

```
server {

            listen 80;
            server_name example.com;

            index index.html;

            location / {
                    root /var/www/example.com;
                    index index.html;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Would this keep the same route in the address bar? I am trying to have a 404 page that returns the correct status code and just visually in Vue. That we already have by using the standard `path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',`

Comment: You are a life saver

Answer (score 3):

## Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.22.0-alpine
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

## nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

## Build image

```bash
docker build -t ui .
```

## Run container

```bash
docker run -d --name ui -p 80:80 ui
```